# new Maven dependency not recognized

Tags: scala, maven

I added a dependency to a Maven project (Scala based) but after recompiling it the new package can't be found.
The new dependency looks as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.any23</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-any23</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0-incubating</version>
</dependency>
```

Now when I

```
import org.apache.any23._
```

I get

```
Error: object any23 is not a member of package org.apache
```

Anybody an idea what the problem may be?

Answer (score 2):

Look in your .m2/repository directory for the jar file. E.g. in OSX Terminal or Linux:

```
find ~/.m2 -print
```

Then use unzip or jar to list the contents:

```
jar tf filename
```

and look for the general package/class names.

You will most likely discover the problem, whatever it is, by looking for the file and contents.

Update: I just looked, it seems that you likely want the core artifact instead:

artifactId: apache-any23-core

it has JAR files, which are more likely to contain what you want: classes.

Comment: "find ~/.m2 -print | grep any23" returns nothing

Comment: I'd say you found your problem. Find a maven repository that has the files you want and add that to your <repositories> section. Just looked and that is the correct dependency name. Found it at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/any23/apache-any23/0.7.0-incubating/

Comment: Ok, I changed the artifactId to core, validated and compiled the project. Nothing changed :(

Comment: Do my original steps again. This works fine for me, and I end up with a jar file that has the code desired: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.any23</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-any23-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0-incubating</version>
</dependency>